# The DateTime represented by the string is not supported and String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string aa = txtsd.Text;
            string bb = txtendd.Text;
            DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(aa);
            DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(bb);
            //DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(bb,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ur-PK").DateTimeFormat);
            //DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtendd.Text.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            TimeSpan ts = (dt1 - dt2);
```

The above code which I have tried in many ways is to calculate the two dates but I keep on getting two errors can any help me in sorting out the two errors.

Errors- 
1] The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.
2] string was not recognized as a valid datetime.

Comment: Could you provide an example of string which you want to convert to DateTime?

Comment: I'm assuming that `txtsd` and `txtendd` needs to be parsed in a safer manner? I could simply enter any string such as "My dog is always hungry"...

Comment: Unless you provide us with the text you're trying to parse we can't help.

Answer (score 1):

The methods you are looking for are:

- [DateTime.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [DateTime.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [DateTime.ParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2)

As this is from user input I would suggest the `Try` variants.

An example if you know the format and it's not the default for your culture:

```
var stringDateTime = "15/01/2013";
DateTime date;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(stringDateTime, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
   // awesome lets do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string aa = "15/01/2000";
        string bb = "20/01/2000";
        DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(aa, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(bb, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
        TimeSpan ts = (dt1 - dt2);

        Console.WriteLine($"Difference: {ts.Days}");
        Console.ReadKey();
```